# Distinct kernels of linear maps $\mathbb R^n \to\mathbb C$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mu,\lambda\colon\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb C$ be linear maps such that $\mu$ is not of the form $r\lambda$ for some $r\in\Bbb R$. Can someone prove that the kernels of $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are not equal?

EDIT: I found the solution. It turns out that the maps in question, despite originally being defined as maps into $\Bbb C$, could be proved to take only real values. Now the statement *is* true for maps $\mu,\lambda\colon\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$, which can be realised in several ways. First of all, such maps are really inner products with elements of $\Bbb R^n$, so the kernels are really the orthogonal complements to certain elements of $\Bbb R^n$; now these ortogonal complements are equal if and only if those elements of $\Bbb R^n$ are multiples of each other.

Another, slightly more elegant solution is to observe that we may assume without loss of generality that $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are non-zero maps which are not multiples of each other. Hence we may find $x,y\in\Bbb R^n$ such that the determinant
$$
\begin{vmatrix}\mu(x) & \lambda(x)\\\mu(y) & \lambda(y)\end{vmatrix}
$$
is non-zero. Hence
$$
\mu(x)\lambda(y)-\mu(y)\lambda(y)=\mu(\lambda(y)x-\lambda(x)y)\neq 0.
$$
But clearly $\lambda(\lambda(y)x-\lambda(x)y) = \lambda(y)\lambda(x)-\lambda(x)\lambda(y) = 0$, so we have found an element $\lambda(y)x-\lambda(x)y$ in the kernel of $\lambda$, but not in the kernel of $\mu$. Similarly, we can find an element of the latter not belonging to the former. Hence the kernels are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true.

Consider this: $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{C}$, $\lambda(x,y)=x+iy$ and $\mu(x,y)=ix+y$.
Both functions have same kernel that is $\{(0,0)\}$ but not real multiples of each other.

Comment: You're right. Then what I need to prove must be something else. I'll probably return once I find the right question to ask. Thank you. :-)

Comment: @Gaussler, perhaps the question should be considered for $r\in\Bbb C$?

Comment: Well I do need the weaker condition of real multiples. Plus, the above counterexamples are not complex multiples of each other either.